# SQL - Display value selected in WHERE <column> IN clause

Tags: sql, sybase

**SOLVED** (see below)

I have the following table (only relevant columns and rows are displayed):

```
table_1
| result | date       | id |  
|--------|------------|----|  
| A      | 12.04.2020 | 42 |    
| B      | 15.04.2020 | 42 |  
| B      | NULL       | 42 |  
| C      | NULL       | 42 |  
| C      | 05.04.2020 | 42 |  
| A      | 23.02.2019 | 43 | 
| B      | 25.02.2019 | 43 | 
| ...    | ...        | ...|
```

I have the following statement (it does not do exactly what I want and should be modified):

```
SELECT result, date, id 
-- some joins to get all data from different tables, I hope it is not relevant for this
FROM table_1 
WHERE result LIKE '%A%' 
AND NOT date = NULL
AND id IN 
(
  SELECT id 
  FROM table_1 
  -- some joins which I also hope are not relevant... 
  WHERE result LIKE '%B%' 
  AND NOT date = NULL 
);
```

What is displayed by the query:

```
| result | date       | id |  
|--------|------------|----|  
| A      | 12.04.2020 | 42 |    
| A      | 23.02.2019 | 43 | 
| ...    | ...        | ...|
```

What I want to be displayed:

```
| result | date       | id |  
|--------|------------|----|  
| A      | 15.04.2020 | 42 |    
| A      | 25.02.2019 | 43 | 
| ...    | ...        |... |
```

The problem:
I don't want the date '12.04.2020' which is the date from the result = A row, but '15.04.2020', which is the date from:

```
| B      | 15.04.2020 | 42 |
```

So, I need the date which is selected in the subquery:

```
(
  SELECT id 
  FROM table_1 
  -- some joins which I also hope are not relevant... 
  WHERE result LIKE '%B%' 
  AND NOT date = NULL 
)
```

The real world problem is much more complex, but the relevant part for me should be the same as presented here.

How do I do that?

Thank you very much in advance!

**Solution:**
(Thanks to @**markp-fuso** who gave the correct and precise answer, see below, and thanks to @**Andy3B** who understood my problem - due to my poor description - and gave basically the right answer!)
**A self join.**

```
SELECT t1.result, t2.date, t1.id 
FROM   table_1 t1 
JOIN   table_1 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 

WHERE  t1.result LIKE '%A%' 
AND    t1.date IS NOT NULL 
AND    t2.result LIKE '%B%' 
AND    t2.date IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Your goal is not clear here (to me). Please add more detail to the description of your logic, and add an Expected Result to the question.

Comment: I am sorry, thank you for your response. I edited my question and I hope my problem is clear, now.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS are you working with (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and what is the datatype of the `table_.date` column?

Comment: what happens if there are multiple rows that meet your criteria (eg, 2+ rows with 'A', 2+ rows with 'B')?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, @Andy3B posted what I needed. The solution was a self join (SQL Noob here who forgot every single SQL concept learned a long time ago...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- for a given `id` value there is at most 1x row where `result=A` and at most 1x row where `result=B` (otherwise OP needs to provide more details on which row(s) are desired if there are 2+ matching rows)
- if there is no matching row with `result=B` then display a NULL (otherwise OP will need to provide more details if a matching `result=B` row does not exist)

We'll let the main query find all the rows with `result=A`, and a sub-query (in the select/projection list) to find the matching row with `result=B`, eg:

```
select  t1.result,
        (select max(t2.date)
         from   table_1 t2
         where  t2.id = t1.id
         and    t2.result like '%B%'
         and    t2.date is not NULL) as 'date',
        t1.id
from    table_1 t1
where   t1.result like '%A%'
and     t1.date is not NULL
```

**NOTE**: The `max(t2.date)` assumes that we want the 'latest' `date` if there are 2+ matching rows with `result=B`; this also assumes the `date` column is of type `(small)datetime`

---

Updating Andy3B's answer to pull values from 2x different rows (the difference in queries is with the first line, the select/projection list):

```
SELECT  T1.result, T2.date, T1.id
FROM    table_1 T1
JOIN    table_1 T2  ON  T2.ID = T1.ID

WHERE 
        T1.result   LIKE    '%A%' 
    AND T1.date     IS      NOT NULL
    AND T2.result   LIKE    '%B%' 
    AND T2.date     IS      NOT NULL
```

**NOTE**: The equijoin assumes there will always be (at least) one row with `result=B` to go with each row where `result=A`.

Answer (score 0):

Nulls should be compared using `date IS NOT NULL` condition instead of `NOT date = NULL`.

Also, you want date `15.04.2020` but the where condition `result LIKE '%A%'` does not match any row with this date.

Try to describe verbosely what do you want to achieve. To select rows with date `15.04.2020`, the inner subquery in `IN` clause is good start.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will correct my code according to your suggestions! I edited my question and I hope the problem is now clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  T2.*
FROM    table_1 T1
JOIN    table_1 T2  ON  T2.ID = T1.ID

WHERE 
        T1.result   LIKE    '%A%' 
    AND T1.date     IS      NOT NULL
    AND T2.result   LIKE    '%B%' 
    AND T2.date     IS      NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you! This goes in the right direction. Didn't use SQL in a long time and a self join could be the solution. I have now trouble to get it work with all the joins in the real world problem as table_1 does not really contain 'id' as a column...

Comment: except this answer doesn't provide the desired results; the desired results want the `result` value from one row and the `date` value from a different row ... while this answer gives just the values from the 1 row where `result=A` (`select T1.*`)

Comment: i tried with his data and got exactly the desired result

Comment: @Andy3B OP's desired result set includes a row with `id=42`,  `result=A` and `date=15.04.2020`, but there is no single row in the original data set with all of these values, so the `SELECT T1.*` will only show the values from one row (see my answer for an update to your query that I believe should provide the desired results); if my version of your query does the job, feel free to update your answer and I'll remove my version of your query from my answer

Comment: i don't know what you mean with original data. there is only one table, and is related to itself; so, all the original data is there. Again, i tested with his data and got exactly his desired result.

Comment: Sorry mark-fuso, i see now. He wants the date of B. You are correct he needs T2.date. Actually i don't recall to read this part in the initial question.

Comment: @Andy3B no problem, the original question was a bit confusing and it's easy to get the 2 sets of output (incorrect vs desired) mixed up; um, your updated query now shows the wrong `result=B` value ... you'll need a mix of T1.x and T2.x columns in the select/projection list

Comment: I edited my solution. I think replacing t1.* by t2,* will do it.

Answer (score 0):

In your case if you make a condition LIKE '%B%' in the end of external select the result will be as you want.

Otherwise, all tuples have the same ID and sampling by ID does not work here.